# Unity : CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to recompile android resource files

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, build

I'm new to Unity. 
When trying to build the android apk, I have an compiling error.
I updated Unity (5.6), SDK(24), JDK(1.8.0)

Seems to have a problem with Java, however I don't understand it.

Does anyone ever had the same issue ? 
Thanks a lot.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to recompile android resource files.
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac -bootclasspath "/Users/kwij1/Desktop/Android SDK/platforms/android-24/android.jar" -d "/Users/kwij1/Sudokubykwij - 1702/Temp/StagingArea/bin/classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 "android/support/v4/Manifest.java" "android/support/v4/R.java" "com/SCGames/SudokuGold/Manifest.java" "com/SCGames/SudokuGold/R.java" "com/android/vending/billing/Manifest.java" "com/android/vending/billing/R.java" "com/area730/localnotif/Manifest.java" "com/area730/localnotif/R.java" "com/facebook/ads/Manifest.java" "com/facebook/ads/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/Manifest.java" "com/google/android/gms/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/ads/Manifest.java" "com/google/android/gms/ads/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/ads/impl/Manifest.java" "com/google/android/gms/ads/impl/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/auth/Manifest.java" "com/google/android/gms/auth/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/auth/api/Manifest.java" "com/google/android/gms/auth/api/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/base/Manifest.java" "com/google/android/gms/base/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/clearcut/Manifest.java" "com/google/android/gms/clearcut/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/drive/Manifest.java" "com/google/android/gms/drive/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/games/Manifest.java" "com/google/android/gms/games/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/gass/Manifest.java" "com/google/android/gms/gass/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/gcm/Manifest.java" "com/google/android/gms/gcm/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/iid/Manifest.java" "com/google/android/gms/iid/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/location/Manifest.java" "com/google/android/gms/location/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/nearby/Manifest.java" "com/google/android/gms/nearby/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/tasks/Manifest.java" "com/google/android/gms/tasks/R.java" "com/google/android/youtube/player/Manifest.java" "com/google/android/youtube/player/R.java" "com/google/example/games/mainlibproj/Manifest.java" "com/google/example/games/mainlibproj/R.java" "com/google/unity/Manifest.java" "com/google/unity/R.java" "com/onesignal/Manifest.java" "com/onesignal/R.java" "com/onesignal/onesignalsdk/Manifest.java" "com/onesignal/onesignalsdk/R.java" "com/pushok/test/Manifest.java" "com/pushok/test/R.java" "com/unity/purchasing/Manifest.java" "com/unity/purchasing/R.java" "com/unity/purchasing/amazon/Manifest.java" "com/unity/purchasing/amazon/R.java" "com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/Manifest.java" "com/unity/purchasing/googleplay/R.java" "com/unity/purchasing/samsung/Manifest.java" "com/unity/purchasing/samsung/R.java" "com/voxelbusters/utility/Manifest.java" "com/voxelbusters/utility/R.java"

stderr[
android/support/v4/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                               ^
android/support/v4/R.java:114: error: illegal start of type
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                 ^
android/support/v4/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                  ^
android/support/v4/R.java:115: error: underscores in literals are not supported in -source 1.6
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)
android/support/v4/R.java:115: error: illegal underscore
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                   ^
android/support/v4/R.java:115: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                          ^
com/SCGames/SudokuGold/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                               ^
com/SCGames/SudokuGold/R.java:114: error: illegal start of type
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                 ^
com/SCGames/SudokuGold/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                  ^
com/SCGames/SudokuGold/R.java:115: error: underscores in literals are not supported in -source 1.6
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)
com/SCGames/SudokuGold/R.java:115: error: illegal underscore
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                   ^
com/SCGames/SudokuGold/R.java:115: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                          ^
com/android/vending/billing/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                               ^
com/android/vending/billing/R.java:114: error: illegal start of type
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                 ^
com/android/vending/billing/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                  ^
com/android/vending/billing/R.java:115: error: underscores in literals are not supported in -source 1.6
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)
com/android/vending/billing/R.java:115: error: illegal underscore
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                   ^
com/android/vending/billing/R.java:115: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                          ^
com/area730/localnotif/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                               ^
com/area730/localnotif/R.java:114: error: illegal start of type
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                 ^
com/area730/localnotif/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                  ^
com/area730/localnotif/R.java:115: error: underscores in literals are not supported in -source 1.6
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)
com/area730/localnotif/R.java:115: error: illegal underscore
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                   ^
com/area730/localnotif/R.java:115: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                          ^
com/facebook/ads/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                               ^
com/facebook/ads/R.java:114: error: illegal start of type
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                 ^
com/facebook/ads/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                  ^
com/facebook/ads/R.java:115: error: underscores in literals are not supported in -source 1.6
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)
com/facebook/ads/R.java:115: error: illegal underscore
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                   ^
com/facebook/ads/R.java:115: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                          ^
com/google/android/gms/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                               ^
com/google/android/gms/R.java:114: error: illegal start of type
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                 ^
com/google/android/gms/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                  ^
com/google/android/gms/R.java:115: error: underscores in literals are not supported in -source 1.6
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)
com/google/android/gms/R.java:115: error: illegal underscore
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                   ^
com/google/android/gms/R.java:115: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                          ^
com/google/android/gms/ads/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                               ^
com/google/android/gms/ads/R.java:114: error: illegal start of type
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                 ^
com/google/android/gms/ads/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                  ^
com/google/android/gms/ads/R.java:115: error: underscores in literals are not supported in -source 1.6
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)
com/google/android/gms/ads/R.java:115: error: illegal underscore
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                   ^
com/google/android/gms/ads/R.java:115: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                          ^
com/google/android/gms/ads/impl/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                               ^
com/google/android/gms/ads/impl/R.java:114: error: illegal start of type
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                 ^
com/google/android/gms/ads/impl/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                  ^
com/google/android/gms/ads/impl/R.java:115: error: underscores in literals are not supported in -source 1.6
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)
com/google/android/gms/ads/impl/R.java:115: error: illegal underscore
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                   ^
com/google/android/gms/ads/impl/R.java:115: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                          ^
com/google/android/gms/auth/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                               ^
com/google/android/gms/auth/R.java:114: error: illegal start of type
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                 ^
com/google/android/gms/auth/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                  ^
com/google/android/gms/auth/R.java:115: error: underscores in literals are not supported in -source 1.6
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)
com/google/android/gms/auth/R.java:115: error: illegal underscore
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                   ^
com/google/android/gms/auth/R.java:115: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                          ^
com/google/android/gms/auth/api/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                               ^
com/google/android/gms/auth/api/R.java:114: error: illegal start of type
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                 ^
com/google/android/gms/auth/api/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                  ^
com/google/android/gms/auth/api/R.java:115: error: underscores in literals are not supported in -source 1.6
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)
com/google/android/gms/auth/api/R.java:115: error: illegal underscore
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                   ^
com/google/android/gms/auth/api/R.java:115: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                          ^
com/google/android/gms/base/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                               ^
com/google/android/gms/base/R.java:114: error: illegal start of type
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                 ^
com/google/android/gms/base/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                  ^
com/google/android/gms/base/R.java:115: error: underscores in literals are not supported in -source 1.6
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)
com/google/android/gms/base/R.java:115: error: illegal underscore
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                   ^
com/google/android/gms/base/R.java:115: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                          ^
com/google/android/gms/clearcut/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                               ^
com/google/android/gms/clearcut/R.java:114: error: illegal start of type
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                 ^
com/google/android/gms/clearcut/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                  ^
com/google/android/gms/clearcut/R.java:115: error: underscores in literals are not supported in -source 1.6
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)
com/google/android/gms/clearcut/R.java:115: error: illegal underscore
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                   ^
com/google/android/gms/clearcut/R.java:115: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                          ^
com/google/android/gms/drive/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                               ^
com/google/android/gms/drive/R.java:114: error: illegal start of type
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                 ^
com/google/android/gms/drive/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                                  ^
com/google/android/gms/drive/R.java:115: error: underscores in literals are not supported in -source 1.6
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)
com/google/android/gms/drive/R.java:115: error: illegal underscore
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                   ^
com/google/android/gms/drive/R.java:115: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 256_circle=0x7f020001;
                                          ^
com/google/android/gms/games/R.java:114: error: <identifier> expected
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                               ^
com/google/android/gms/games/R.java:114: error: illegal start of type
        public static final int 1=0x7f020000;
                  <message truncated>
```

Comment: Do you update your java or Android sdk? Some times Unity has some troubles working with the recent updates and the solutions is to get back to an alder version. Can you build an empty android project witouth errors?

Comment: Hi @SalvadorLemus, thanks for your tips. I build an empty android project without errors. Does it means that java and android sdk are fine and the trouble come from a module ?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed 2 issues that prevented from building an apk:
1. Multiple Android support library JARs (one in Facebook audience network)
2. Assets starting with numbers
Thanks